# jQuery.noConflict() is not working for popup box

Tags: html, css, popup, jquery

I am having a webpage with 3 slider and one popup box.
 For sliders i used `jQuery.noConflict()` so that is working fine.
 but in the case of popup box if i am using `jQuery.noConflict()` its not working.
If i am not using `jQuery.noConflict()` then my slider wont work.

**popup html**

```
<div id="popupContact">
  <a id="popupContactClose"><img src="close.gif" alt="close"/></a>
  <div id="contactArea"></div>
</div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

**popup jquery**

```
var popupStatus = 0;
function loadPopup(){
  if(popupStatus==0){
    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "opacity": "0.2"
    });
    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
    popupStatus = 1;
  }
}

function disablePopup(){
  if(popupStatus==1){
    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
    popupStatus = 0;
  }
}

function centerPopup(){
  var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
  var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
  $("#popupContact").css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
    "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
  });
  $("#backgroundPopup").css({
    "height": windowHeight
  });
}

var $rp = jQuery.noConflict();
$rp(document).ready(function(){ 
  $rp("#buttonpop").click(function(){
    centerPopup();
    loadPopup();
  });
  $rp("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
    disablePopup();
  });
  $rp("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
    disablePopup();
  });
  $rp(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
        disablePopup();
    }
 });
});
```

**Note:**  This popup jquery is an external jquery and i am using `<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` also.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `jQuery.noConflict()`, that prevents jQuery from aliasing `jQuery` as `$`. However your popup code is still trying to use `$`.

Either reference `jQuery`, not `$`, or wrap your code in a closure and reference `$` as a local variable within the closure, i.e.

```
(function($) {
    //popup code here
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: If i am trying the above instruction, then its effecting my slider also.